# git log on a pre-filtered subset of the history

Tags: git, reporting, git-log

I'd like to use git log to show a set of diffs between commits that I have filtered myself. git log does have an internal history filtering ability that will (when used with the --patch flag) show diffs between commits that may be far apart in the history. But when I try to combine that with --stdin to pass a list of commits, I get the full history of these commits (actually the full history of the branch they are on). Adding -1 does not get me closer to the desired behaviour, it just limits me to one commit total.

I'm looking for a cleaner version of this (daily diffs of all commits that occured during the last few weeks):

```bsh
git log --date=short --format='%H %ad' --since 2012-05-15 \
  |uniq -f1 |while read hash date
do
  if [[ -n $hash0 ]]; then
    echo ${date}..${date0}
    git diff $hash $hash0
  fi
  hash0=$hash
  date0=$date
done |less
```

Comment: Your script and your second paragraph don't really match your first paragraph very well -- where's --stdin? what filtering? you mention 'far apart in the history' but nothing like that appears in the script?

Comment: more oddities: what's the uniq filter for? why are you formatting the author date and throwing it away? where's the list of commits you've filtered yourself? shell pipes use stdout/stdin, and xargs reads stdin, should --stdin on your last git log be reading some other file?

Comment: The second paragraph is my hacky solution that sort of works, though it doesn't use the git log format. What I described in the first paragraph is my ideal solution, which would be a working version of this: `git log --date=short --format='%H %ad' --since 2012-05-15 |uniq -f1 |awk '{print $1}' |xargs git log --stdin`.

Comment: `uniq`, and the date which I throw away, are used to get one commit per day. You can try the left side of the pipe on your own repos.

Comment: my mistake on the `uniq -f1`, I had it as `cut`'s `-f`.  at the last stage of your pipeline, you're using xargs to pass stdin's contents as git log arguments, so --stdin is redundant.  But you don't want the history of those commits, you want diffs between specific pairs of commits.  Your script does that.  What doesn't it do that you want it to do?